# Split 10 digit number in div into 3,3,4 with jQuery using split or length

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

Using Digital Bush's maskedInput plugin to format a phone number and then breaking that phone number out of the mask and into a div. I need to split that divs content into 3,3,and 4... i.e. I need to break it into 3 inputs (which will eventually be hidden) to send that back to the server. So far I have everything working except the split and I may be using that wrong instead of breaking it up using length.

Here is a working fiddle of what I have right now:

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/egxmE/)

I have this right here:

```
 <input id="txtPhoneNumber" name="FancyPhoneNumber" class="required phone" type="text" />
        <div id="txtHiddenPhoneNumber2"></div>
```

Which takes the users input and puts the stripped down value (10 numbers) into a div. Then I am taking that div and putting it into three input fields.

```
$("#txtPhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
                $("#txtPhoneNumber").blur(function () {
                    $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber").val("");
                    var charArray = $(this).val().split("");
                    var phoneNumber = "";

                    $.each(charArray, function(index, value) {
                        if (!isNaN(value) && value != " ") {
                            phoneNumber = phoneNumber + value;
                        }
                    });

                    $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber2").append("<div>"+phoneNumber+"</div>")
                    var data =$('#txtHiddenPhoneNumber2').text();
                    var arr = data.match(/.{3}/g);
                    $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber2").html("<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[0] +"'>" + "<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[1]+"'>" + "<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[2] +"'>");
                });
```

It's working as I need only it is not sending the last digit to the last input field which is being populated with arr[2]. I assume I am trying to use split wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: data.match(/.{3}/g); will match only 3 digits, thats why arr[2] has only 3 digits. You may try data.match(/.{3,4}/g);

Comment: I just read that. Thank you. So I guess I need to use slice and slice it up at 3 and 7 and send those vals to the arrays.

Comment: Since I don't have the mask plugin I am not able to run it. What will be the value of $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber2") ? will it be with brackets and hiphen? then data.match(/.{3,4}/g); might work for you

Comment: the fiddle has a working example. Basically, I am using the mask to format for the user so they can read it easily, then putting that value into a hidden div and breaking that into three hidden inputs to pass to the backend for data collection. The link for the fiddle is above but here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/egxmE/  it looks like I need to slice it again but I can't see how to reuse the slice

Comment: actually, slice may not work... I need to break a 10 digit value into 3 parts...

Comment: For some reason the fiddle is not working for me. I have commented out the mask part in this fiddle. please see may be this helps http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/m4LhT/1/

Comment: `'0123456789'.match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/).splice(1)`

Comment: I see that and that is one of the problems I had, using that method it only splits it into 4 and then shows undefined... I'll keep researching. Thank you.

Comment: This is a working fiddle with the answer that [Sajith Nair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1733710/sajith-nair) provided: http://jsfiddle.net/egxmE/1/

Comment: I know. I gave him the win. It was the fiddle that I had that did not work with his RegEx. When I just used his script below it worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtPhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $("#txtPhoneNumber").blur(function () {
        $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber").val("");

        var data =$("#txtPhoneNumber").val();
        var arr = data.match(/\d{3,4}/g);
        $("#txtHiddenPhoneNumber2").html("<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[0] +"'>" + "<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[1]+"'>" + "<input type=\"text\" value='"+arr[2] +"'>");
    });
});
```